# How to switch between graphics cards on Wayland (18.10)?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics, hybrid-graphics, wayland

It's obviously possible to switch between Intel and Nvidia cards on Xorg, using the 'Nvidia X Server Settings' utility, but I haven't found a way to do it in a Wayland session. Any Ideas?